# I want to escape the limit() in db_select

Tags: php, forms, post, drupal, drupal-7

I want to delete the limit() from my code:

```
$query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa')
    -> extend('PagerDefault')
    -> orderBy('wid')
    -> fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity',
      'message', 'wid', 'timestamp'))
    -> limit(2000);
  $result = $query -> execute();
```

and I want the user to select from a form the number to select. How I can do this thing?

Comment: you got some advance?

Comment: nop i cannot solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example:

```
    <?php

    if(!empty($_POST['number'])) {
      $number = $_POST['number'];

    /*
    Add your code here
    */


    $query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa')
        -> extend('PagerDefault')
        -> orderBy('wid')
        -> fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity',
          'message', 'wid', 'timestamp'))
        -> limit($number);
      $result = $query -> execute();

}

    <form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type=text value='' name='number'>
    <input type=submit value='send'>
    </form>
```

Comment: i want the form to be a save form not a submit and i want this form code to be in the .admin.inc file

Answer (score 1):

Swap out "2000" for a variable.  This variable should contain the number that the user has selected.  I can't tell you exactly how to do that because you haven't provided enough code.

Comment: This is an answer to the question @Skatox. The way to let the user choose how much rows to return is to swap `2000` with a variable, bu we can't say anymore because we don't have enough code. sg is right all along.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed the report